# Bind DataGridView to multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, database-design

I've got the following three tables in my database which I want to display to the user in a single DataGridView:

```
RecipeNames     RecipeValue         Ingredient
-----------     -------------       ----------
PK  Name        FK RecipeName      
                FK IngredientName   PK Name
                   Amount
```

The user should see one row per RecipeName, the recipe name being the first column and the ingredient names the following columns. Each cell will contain the amount of a recipeValue and every Recipe has every Ingredient. Also the user must be able to edit any cell add a new recipe by adding a new row. Should look like this:

```
Name     |  Ingredient 1 | ... | Ingredient n |
-----------------------------------------------
Recipe1  |   100         | ... | 1000         |
Recipe2  |   200         | ... | 2000         |
```

At the moment I'm thinking about generating and filling the grid manually like this:

- add columns for each row in the ingredient table
- add rows for each Name in RecipeNames
- fill Cells according to RecipeValue table

Then the user can add / modify stuff in the table. When he hits a "Save" button I iterate over the datagrid again and do the appropriate update/insert operations for each row.

Can this be done automatically? How would you bind the tables to the Datagrid? (I know how databinding works for a single table/view, but am at a loss how to do it in this case)

Also any comment on the design is welcome.

*edit to clarify:* the tables are simplified, there are more fields to them, among them an ID number as primary key and the queries will be limited by other parameters so that only a few ingredients will be listed. I primarily want to know ways to present such a table design in a datagrid or similiar UI which keeps the development effort minimal.

Comment: From a UI perspective, if the number of ingredients is large, this will be unwieldy.  Horizontal scrolling is generally something to avoid if other options exist.  Have you considered a master-detail table pair where you select the recipe in the master table and edit the ingredient values in the detail table?

Comment: The tables are a bit simplified, theres an extra condition which ingredients apply and so the number of columns is limited. Also the user should be able to see the differences between two recipies without clicking in them.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please not work with strings as primary or foreign keys? That is really bad practice and if you're working with MSSQL (which I guess) you're turning down the server's speed.

```
tblRecipeNames  AsRecipeValue       tblIngredients    tblAmountTypes
-----------     -------------       ----------        ----------
PK ID           PK ID               PK ID             PK ID
   Name         FK RecName_ID          Name              Name
                FK Ingredient_ID
                FK AmountType
                   Amount
```

I renamed your RecipeValue because this table is an "association table" so that's where the "As" comes from. I also added IDs to every table because that's what you should be working with.

The new table AmountTypes is because of the different types:

- teaspoon
- tablespoon
- large
- medium
- small
- cup
- zest

and so on.

After that and now **coming back to your question**, first of all you generate stored procedures for your getters and setters. You want to seperate your SQL-Server as the "Hard-Drive" you're getting information from since it's the fastest way to handle data.

For Example:

```
SELECT * FROM tblRecipeNames 
        INNER JOIN AsRecipeValue ON tblRecipeNames.ID = AsRecipeValue.RecName_ID
        INNER JOIN tblIngredients ON tblIngredients.ID = AsRecipeValue.Ingredient_ID
```

That's the first step. If you're there you can add a SqlDatasource to your GridView and in the site you add your stored procedures to the control like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlSrc" runat="server" InsertCommand="spInsert" DeleteCommand="spDelete" UpdateCommand="spUpdate" />
```

sp* stands for your own stored procedure.

Comment: Why extra ID for the association table? I'm using (RecName_ID, Ingredient_ID) as a key. Which also enforces that each Ingredient appears only once. Nice idea with the AmountType table, although it is not needed in my application.

Comment: @grimmig the ID stands for that association. When I'm working into some deep database stuff I always recommend my students to create extra IDs. Just to know in which association they really are at that point. I agree to the point that it seem's a bit useless at first sight.